# WPF ComboBox loses binding after click

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, itemssource

I have a ComboBox that is ItemsSource bound to a custom class' property. It is also SelectedItem bound to an other property of that class.
When I click the Combo while it's not populated yet, it never seems to populate (the ItemsSource property is filled with data).
If I don't click the ComboBox before it populates, the binding and population works fine.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,75,0" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WP_API.FTPConnections}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=WP_API.SelectedFTPConnection}"
           DisplayMemberPath="Host"
           SelectedValuePath="Host"/>
```

Comment: can you post your complete code

Comment: It's seem's that your property WP_API.FTPConnections doesn't implements INotifyCollectionChanged. Anyway, please put your properties code here.

Comment: @Spawn You're right on the money. The class where the property is set/stored is not implementing BindableBase interface, so I didn't implement the SetProperty as in ViewModels. I have now moved those properties to ViewModel and added the SetPoperty and all is well now.
Please let me know how to reward this answer to you.